# My emulator displays a bigger status bar rather than the one which is displayed in the design part.I'm new to android studio

Tags: android-studio

The image given below represents the screenshot of what is being displayed inside my emulator.The status bar looks bigger.

[Screenshot][1]

One more problem is that I cant find my application icon anywhere inside the
emulator but my application runs smoothly when I run the program.

Comment: Your question requires editing. Please use [Ask us](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-asks) guide to learn how to frame a question. Welcome to Stack overflow.

Comment: @Josh (and others), I believe the question should be in fact closed. It lacks focus and clarity. In fact, two questions are being asked